# How do I make machine exits responses return JSON?

Tags: sails.js

Sails returns the name of the HTTP response in the body of the request for machine exits (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/issues/910):

```
 exits: {
    emailAlreadyInUse: {
      statusCode: 409,
      description: 'The provided email address is already in use.'
    }
  }
```

This gives me the error response in the headers of the response:

```
X-Exit →emailAlreadyInUse
X-Exit-Description →The provided email address is already in use.
```

How do I return these in a normal JSON response so it is consistent with other responses which look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your exit, you could include a Response Type, which allows you to set a custom response in sails.

```
exits: {
    emailAlreadyInUse: {
      statusCode: 409,
      responseType: 'jsonResponse',
      description: 'The provided email address is already in use.'
    }
}
```

Next, you create your custom response in api/responses and you set it the way you like.

```
module.exports = function jsonResponse() {
    let req = this.req;
    let res = this.res;
    sails.log.verbose('Ran custom response: res.jsonResponse()');
    /* DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO */
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Ok great, how do I pass the description from the exit to the custom response?

Comment: You could move it from req.headers to res.exit.message for example

Comment: What do you mean exactly with this answer? I have the same issue, and I didn't really get your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you did not find the solution, send the text directly in the response:

```
return this.res.json('Hello World!');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try/catch block on your action and in the catch block check for `error.code` and return the needed JSON response. For example. You have:

```js
  fn: async function ({name, email, password}, exits) {
    try {

      const user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password
      })
      .fetch()

      return exits.success({success: true, user})

    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === 'E_UNIQUE') {
        return exits.emailAlreadyInUse({success: false, message: 'The provided email is already in use by a switter user.'})
      } else if (error.name === 'UsageError') {
       return exits.badRequest({ success: false, message: 'Missing or invalid parameter')

      }
    }
  }
```

Mostly the description on the exit is mostly for the response header. So you have to set the values you want to send back same way you will set the values for a success exit.

Do not that for the `else if` block to get triggered, your waterline model should have some validations like `required: true`, `isEmail: true` or so and your actions inputs should not have `required: true` as that will validate before even your action code is run making Sails send the default response for invalid or missing params.